# Transaction getEstimatedFee returning null

Tags: web3.js, solana-sdk

I am trying to use the sdk to estimate gas fees on a transaction. However, `transaction.getEstimatedFee(connection)` sometimes returns null. I cannot figure out why and there is no error message. Would this be due to my node?

Answer (score 4):

That method will return `null` if the blockhash in your transaction has expired.

Make sure to freshen up the `recentBlockhash` before trying to fetch the fee.

```
const {blockhash} = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
transaction.getEstimatedFee(connection);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I was using await connection.getLatestBlockhash(finalized) so I guess sometimes it would be expired. Thanks!